# Generate new transaction Id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL which used to generate the Transaction Id. I am extracting last 3 digits from the present string and increment by 1.

**Example:**

If

```
--> 001 Then 002
--> 123 Then 124
```

The query what I have tried,

```
DECLARE @TransactionId NVARCHAR(100)

SET @TransactionId= CONVERT(nvarchar,(SELECT SUBSTRING('PM16520001', 8, 10)))

SELECT @TransactionId as TranId
SET @TransactionId = CONVERT(Nvarchar,@TransactionId + 1)


SELECT @TransactionId as TranId
```

Actual Result:

```
2
```

Expected Result:

```
002
```

Comment: right('00'+cast(result as varchar(3)),3)

Comment: `NVARCHAR` without a length specifier is [a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it adds 2 zeros to your result and takes the right 3 characters. in your 112 case then right(00112,3) = 112. In the case of 2 then right(002,3)=002.

Comment: @KeithL yes got that! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main concern is padding your result with 0's.

The fastest way to do that on your numneric is to concat the max pad value to the casted result as max pad

using the following:

```
Right('00' + cast(result as varchar(3)), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would cover the last three digits. 
the process will be casting the last three digits to INT, then check their length to determine how many leading zeros to input.

```
DECLARE @TransactionId NVARCHAR(100)

SET @TransactionId= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(SELECT SUBSTRING('PM16520001', 8, 10)))

SELECT
@TransactionId =  
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(CAST(RIGHT(@TransactionId, 3) AS INT)) = 1 
        THEN '00' + CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@TransactionId, 3) AS INT) + 1 AS NVARCHAR)
        WHEN LEN(CAST(RIGHT(@TransactionId, 3) AS INT)) = 2 
        THEN '0' + CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@TransactionId, 3) AS INT) + 1 AS NVARCHAR)
        ELSE CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@TransactionId, 3) AS INT) + 1 AS NVARCHAR)
    END 


SELECT @TransactionId as TranId
```

So if the transaction id is `PM16520001` then the output should be `002`, and if the transction id is `PM16520015` the output should be `016`, and if the transaction id is `PM16520305` the output should be `306` and so on.

if is it a business requirement, I would suggest using a scalar function to build a function that would be more flexible in reused across the system. Also, this would give an advantage of adding, modifying the logic whenever needed in one place to be applied everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!